Was the position of Jesus crucified among thieves, predetermined?
We read in Lk 23:32-33( NIV):

Two others, who were criminals, were also led away to be executed with Jesus.l When they reached the place called The Skull, they crucified him there with the criminals, one on his right and one on his left.

Within a group of people numbering more than two, the most important person is given the middle position, the finest example being a group portrait.But,  in the case of convicts of death penalty, the position hardly matters. In the case of Jesus, his position seems to have been predetermined- either by divine intervention, or by the crafty decision of Jewish leaders who wanted to insult him to the maximum possible projecting him as the most wanted criminal of the three.
Of course, we hear Jesus
quoting  Isiah 53:12  in Lk 22:37 :

For I say unto you, that this that is written must yet be accomplished in me, And he was reckoned among the transgressors: for the things concerning me have an end.

That prophecy would  stand  fulfilled even if Jesus was NOT crucified at the centre, for instance, with the Good Thief at the centre and Jesus on one side .
My question therefore is : Was the position of  Jesus crucified among thieves, predetermined ? Are there any extra-biblical writings  available on the subject ?

The question of whether the position of Jesus crucified among the thieves was predetermined can be illuminated by several biblical passages that evoke the crucifixion and the prophetic context.
Biblical Answer

Prophecy in Isaiah:
•   Isaiah 53:12: "Therefore I will give him his share among the great, and he will share the spoils with the powerful, because he has stripped himself to death, and has been put among the evildoers." This verse predicts that the Messiah would be associated with the evildoers, which can be interpreted as an indication of how Jesus would be crucified.
Fulfillment in the Gospels:
•   Luke 22:37: "For this scripture must be fulfilled in me: 'He has been put among the evildoers.'" Jesus himself refers to this prophecy, indicating that his crucifixion among the thieves was a fulfillment of the Scriptures.
Theological significance
The crucifixion of Jesus between two thieves emphasizes his identification with sinners and his role as savior. This shows that his mission was to save those who were lost, illustrating the love and grace of God.
Conclusion
Thus, it can be concluded that the position of the crucified Jesus among the robbers was predetermined according to the Scriptures, both in the prophecies of the Old Testament and in their fulfillment in the New Testament. This reinforces the idea that this situation was not accidental, but was an integral part of the divine plan for the salvation of humanity, illustrating the depth of his sacrifice and his identification with sinners.


Was the position of Jesus crucified among thieves predetermined?
Luke 22:22 All ESV

"For the Son of Man goes as it has been determined."

Every detail of Jesus' crucifiction, including the position of Jesus' cross relative to the other two crosses, is summed up in the word "goes". Nothing is random, left to chance, in God's determining.
Acts 4:27-28

"for truly in this city there were gathered together against your holy servant Jesus whom you anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the people of Israel, 28 to do whatever your hand and your plan   had predestined to take place." [My emphasis]

God's predestined gathering included Gentiles e.g., Roman soldiers who placed Jesus' cross in its position. The Lord's unseen hand guided events.
Matthew 6:26

"Look at the birds of the air: they neither sow nor reap nor gather into barns, and yet your heavenly Father feeds them."

We don't see God physically feeding the birds but the Bible says He does. How? God gives birds instincts, direction and abilities to know where to find food. Similarly God can predestinate,  directing the actions of people, including  e.g., the Roman soldiers as they crucified Jesus. [John 19:23 "When they had crucified Jesus"]
Matthew 10:29

"Are not two sparrows sold for a penny. And not one of them will fall to the ground apart from your Father."

ESV "apart from your Father."
NLT "without your Father knowing it."
NIV "outside your Father's care."
Berean B. "apart from the will of your Father."
Here we have the Father involved with the death of one sparrow, knowing, caring about and willing that death. If Almighty God is so involved with the death of one sparrow then He will have thought every detail of the physical death of His beloved Son, including the  positions of the crosses.
Romans 11:36

"For from him and through him and to him are all things."

"all things" is not restricted to some limited category. The details of Jesus' crucifiction are "from him."
The human will is free "to" but not free "from".
The human will, including the will of those who were involved with the details of Jesus' crucifiction, is free to express itself. But not free "from"  God making it, why He made it and how He made it. [All things made through him. John 1:3]
How God makes things, inc' the human will, is fundamental to what they are. What something is, is fundamental to its behaviour. The will of those who chose the positions of the three crosses came "from him".
From Revelation 4:8

"Holy, holy, holy is the Lord God Almighty,"

The unseen hand of God had a holy motive in predestinating/predetermining
the seen human hands which placed "one on his right and one on his left" Luke 23:33.

Yes, the position of Jesus crucified among thieves was predetermined.
We have to remember that the humiliation of the cross was the way Jesus was exalted. It was the day of His enthronement.

27 Then the governor’s soldiers took Jesus into the Praetorium and
gathered the whole company of soldiers around him. 28 They stripped
him and put a scarlet robe on him, 29 and then twisted together a
crown of thorns and set it on his head. They put a staff in his right
hand. Then they knelt in front of him and mocked him. “Hail, king of
the Jews!” they said. (Matthew 27)
19 Pilate had a notice prepared and fastened to the cross. It read:
JESUS OF NAZAREATH, THE KING OF THE JEWS. (John 19)

It was more than likely Pilate, who ordered his soldiers to crucify Jesus in the middle. Which goes hand in hand with the inscription mentioned by John.
But the fact of the mater is that Jesus himself knew He would be crucified in the middle before it happened.

17 Now Jesus was going up to Jerusalem. On the way, he took the Twelve
aside and said to them, 18 “We are going up to Jerusalem, and the Son
of Man will be delivered over to the chief priests and the teachers of
the law. They will condemn him to death 19 and will hand him over to
the Gentiles to be mocked and flogged and crucified. On the third day
he will be raised to life!”  20 Then the mother of Zebedee’s sons came
to Jesus with her sons and, kneeling down, asked a favor of him.
21“What is it you want?” he asked. She said, “Grant that one of these
two sons of mine may sit at your right and the other at your left in
your kingdom.” 22 “You don’t know what you are asking,” Jesus said to
them. “Can you drink the cup I am going to drink?” “We can,” they
answered. 23 Jesus said to them, “You will indeed drink from my cup,
but to sit at my right or left is not for me to grant. These places
belong to those for whom they have been prepared by my Father.”
(Matthew 20)


Thanks ארקדיוס. Pilate in deed, seems to have had a role in deciding that Jesus be crucified in the middle position. It will also be great if you could connect Mtt 20:17-23 with a concluding paragraph.

While the mother of James and John petitions Jesus for her sons' glorification in the world to come, He answers her, talking about His own. On the cross. Paradoxically, Christ crucifixion is the time of His exaltation.

Behold, My Servant will prosper, He will be high and lifted up and greatly exalted. Isaiah 52:13

And I, when I am lifted up from the earth, will draw all people to myself.” He said this to show the kind of death he was going to die. John 12:32-33

That Jesus was crucified between two other thieves is well documented:

Matt 27:38 - Two robbers were crucified with Him, one on His right hand and the other on His left.
Mark 15:27, 28 - Along with Jesus, they crucified two robbers, one on His right and one on His left. So the Scripture was fulfilled that says, “And He was numbered with the transgressors.”
Luke 22:37 - For I tell you that this Scripture must be fulfilled in me: ‘And he was numbered with the transgressors.’ For what is written about me has its fulfillment.”

These verse are directly alluding to and quoting:

Isa 53:12 - Therefore I will allot Him a portion with the great, and He will divide the spoils with the strong, because He has poured out His life unto death, and He was numbered with the transgressors.

Thus, Jesus crucifixion was "according to the Scriptures" as Paul asserts in

1 Cor 15:3 - For what I received I passed on to you as of first
importance: that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures

The above is only one of at least 60 separate OT prophecies about the life, death and resurrection of Jesus that we precisely fulfilled by Jesus' ministry on earth.

You cut short Paul - 1 Cor 15:4 - 4 that he was buried, that he was raised on the third day according to the Scriptures,  - even if you accept 'death' & Isa 53 relates to Jesus (which it doesn’t) - there is no OT about resurrection

Thanks, Dottard. I agree that Jesus'  ' numbering among criminals' had been predetermined and prophesied. But then, the prophecy would be fulfilled even if Jesus was crucified on one side, say, with the Good Thief in the middle. My doubt is why he was made to hang in the middle , with every passerby noticing him .

@another theory: “Thy dead men shall live, together with my dead body shall they arise. Awake and sing, ye that dwell in dust: for thy dew is as the dew of herbs, and the earth shall cast out the dead.” — Isaiah 26:19. The passages before and after show this to be directly related to the advent of Christ.

@AFrazier - I should have made myself clear - there is no OT about Jesus resurrection or being raised after 3 days.  your quote above relates to resurrection of all dead and KJV seems to be the only one that has conveniently added  'together with my dead body' the incorrect translation should be 'their bodies' so more than one person.

Gotcha. I wasn’t aware of that particular difference. Most other reputable translations I checked read as you say. I’ll have to look into the textual criticism on that passage.

@anothertheory - I suggest you examine  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-scriptures-is-paul-referring-to-in-1-cor-154/96790#96790

@Dottard you seem to have forgotten we’ve been there already - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/96806/33268 we were to debate but unfortunately that never materialised

@anothertheory - are you suggesting that Paul was in error and mistaken under inspiration?

@Dottard - very inspired - 1 Corinthians 7:25 Now concerning the unmarried, I have no command of the Lord, but I give my opinion as one who by the Lord’s mercy is trustworthy.  This is Paul's religion - “Remember that Jesus Christ of the seed of David was raised from the dead according to my gospel:” 2 Timothy 2:8

@Dottard something even more inspiring - Romans 15:20 20 It has always been my ambition to preach the gospel where Christ was not known,* so that I would not be building on someone else’s foundation.

@anothertheory - that is where we differ - I believe that the NT - all of it - is the revealed and inspired truth of God about Jesus Christ.  It is NOT based on any human opinion.  Further, Paul NEVER says anything about his opinion - a word he never uses.

@Dottard - opinion / his judgment same thing in the context to the sentence.  Jesus is God as well but Paul appears to want to preach something that has nothing to do with God Jesus  - or are you going to say its only inspired by God the father.

@anothertheory - Thanks for your view.

There are numerous issues with connecting Isaiah 53 with Jesus and resurrection after 3 days.
Isaiah 53:9 - NIV
He was assigned a grave with the wicked, and with the rich in his death, though he had done no violence, nor was any deceit in his mouth.


“in his death” – is an incorrect translation – the Hebrew word is ‘maveth’ which means death or at best in death – symbolic not confirmation of physical death


Somewhat different translation:
Youngs Literal Translation (YLT) –
9 And it appointeth with the wicked his grave, And with the rich [are] his high places, Because he hath done no violence, Nor [is] deceit in his mouth.
New Living Translation (NLT)
9 He had done no wrong and had never deceived anyone. But he was buried like a criminal;he was put in a rich man’s grave.
Contemporary English Version (CEV)
9 He wasn't dishonest or violent, but he was buried in a tomb among cruel, rich people.


Assigned (allocated) a grave with the wicked and rich.  Even if you take, placed in a Tomb as buried – we was by himself in the tomb not with the wicked or rich.**


To imply that ‘assigned a grave’ means he died with the wicked on the cross & the tomb was owned by the rich as satisfying the criteria for the prophecy is illogical.


Bullet points on a number of other issues as to why Isa 53 cannot relate to Jesus;


53:5 But he was wounded [not died, and there is no Hebrew word ‘pierced’]
53:10 shall see his offspring; he shall prolong his days; [Jesus lived till approx. 33 years and did not see his offsprings]


God said he would protect the Messiah;


Psalms 91 - Surely he will save you… / but it will not come near you. / No harm will overtake you,  no disaster will come near your tent. / For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all your ways; /  they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will not strike your foot against a stone. / “Because he loves me,” says the LORD, “I will rescue him; I will protect him,  /  He will call on me, and I will answer him; / With long life I will satisfy him and show him my salvation.”
Psalm 20:6 6Now I know that the LORD saves His anointed; He answers him from His holy heaven with the saving power of His right hand.
“O you who lift me up from the gates of death” (Psalms 9:13)
Psalms 34:20 & 22 - 20He protects all his bones; not one of them will be broken
22 - The LORD will rescue his servants; no one who takes refuge in him will be condemned.
To see more: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/62632/33268
No matter which way you look at it this doesn’t relate to Jesus

Thanks, another theory . My question does not claim the Is 53:12 had foretold the middle position in crucifixion that was assigned to the Lord. I tend to agree with the answer of ארקדיוס in suggesting that Pilate had a say in that position. In the alternative, a Jewish leader , on reading the INRI board meant for Jesus, would have suggested that the King be hanged in the middle with two 'bodyguards' on either side. That remark would have infuriated the Bad Thief to yell at Jesus : " If you are God's Son , save yourself and us ."
